# Button Controlling Animation

Tags: css, webkit

Ok so I've got a project where I am making a cartoon version of a record player. I want the play button on the side to toggle the animation of the record spinning using webkit, while at the same time starting the audio track. The audio track is fine but now sure about affecting the webkit from the button. What's the best way to do this? I'd rather avoid JQuery.

Any nod in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Hello, this tutorial might help you http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/07/12/old-school-cassette-player-with-html5-audio/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about using or affecting WebKit? It is only a rendering engine currently used by Safari, and dropped by Chrome in favour of a fork called Blink. Do you mean you want to use CSS to animate the record?

Comment: @dstorey yes in short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with CSS transforms and CSS animations. The following demo shows how to do the spin:

http://jsfiddle.net/FSkKn/

```
div { 
   /* add -webkit, moz, and o prefixes to the property below */
   /* change 2s to the time you want for one revolution */
   animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes spin {
    /* both the keyframe above and the transform properties below need prefixes */

    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg) ;
    }

    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Now you have something spinning, you just need to trigger it. The best way would be to add a class to the `div` (or element you are using) when the button is clicked. Then add the animation property to a selector with that class, such as:

```
 .spin-baby-spin { 

   animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't get it to work http://jsfiddle.net/FSkKn/1/ what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quite a few issues. See http://jsfiddle.net/FSkKn/2/ for a solution. First of all you've not included the prefixes inside the spin-baby-spin rule. Second of all you added the class to the button. It needs to be added to the div which will spin. BUT only after the button has been clicked. To do that you need to add the class via JS when you click the button. In the demo I've used classList.toggle, but this doesn't have great browser support, so use your favourite method to add and remove classes.

Comment: Sorry about delay, that works I misunderstood what you were getting at before. Thanks so much. I'll have a play about!